# Dynamic contents in a pick list

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I'll be creating a solution where a form will carry a pick list consisting of the names of all the entities declared on the server. That list needs to be dynamically updated for each time it's being used.

The solution I've deployed before is to set up a web resource in an iframe, hance having total control over the dynamic set up of it. It works and it works well.

Now I wonder, of pure curiosity, if it'd be possible to solve it using a the build-in *picklist* component. Perhaps if I used a plugin that fires prior to displaying of the form equipped with the *picklist* and alter the metadata of the underlying set of options declared for it...

Thought on this?
Alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be possible to have a plugin fire on the Create / Update / Delete of an entity (not an object, but the actual metadata for an Entity), that updates a global option set list.  Then you could just let CRM populate it for you...

I don't know about recommended, but it would be supported.

Use the *InsertOptionValueRequest* to add new values.

and this to force a publish:

```csharp
service.Execute( new PublishXmlRequest
{
  ParameterXml = String.Format(
    "<importexportxml><entities><entity>{0}</entity></entities></importexportxml>", 
    "EntitySetLogicalName")
});
```

Comment: Right. Two aspects I'm unsure about. (1) Is it recommended at all (vs doing it "my" way using web resource)? (2) Can you suggest some code to manipulate the metadata (I got only nasty looking atrocities and lost the coding joy)? Not a whole plugin, just the core for altering a certain option set, that is.

Comment: *PublishXmlRequest*? Never seen that before... Care to elaborate? I was trying a different approach, too. I was trying to go without any XML-ish stuff, only a class (can't remember the name right now) for manipulating option sets...

Comment: @KonradViltersten As far as I know, it's the only way to publish your changes to the option set.  It could just work without that as well though...

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I'm just barking up the wrong tree. I was attempting something along `Entity e = service.Retrieve(...)` but with option sets like `OptionSet os = service.Retrieve(...)`. Bad idea? Also, in another post you mentioned that you've built a site for 5000 users with an external access. I see a warning flag there but I prefer to explain that off the record.